# Trying to install Jupyter Notebook but I'm always greeted with 'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I already tried adding path but the problem is I already have (insert path here)\Python310\Scripts in my PATHS.

I also tried to install Python 3.6.8 (since my tutorial said it's ideal) and I thought it might not work with 3.10 but still nothing. In fact I don't even find the Python 3.6 folder that looks like the 3.10 folder on the inside.

Maybe my preinstalled Python version is the problem or is it something else?

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the activated virtual environment where you installed it? Or, did you install Jupyter to the base Python 3.6 installation (or whatever version you are using)?

Comment: I simply try to run it from cmd and also installed it on cmd using 'pip3 install jupyter'

Comment: That package has not been updated since 2015, still you could try `python -m jupyter` or try reading Jupyter's docs

Comment: Also, it would probably make things easier for you if you installed Anaconda on your system. It will include Jupyter.